# Accessing imagecache path inside template

Tags: files, media

I'm using the ImageField module together with Imagecache to display a picture for one of my content types.

To display the content body I'm using Contemplate, I'm accessing the path to the image in the following way:

```
'[...]/imagecache/[preset]/[...]/'.$node->field_picture[0]['filename']
```

This usually works, but it breaks when someone uploads a picture with the same filename as the existing one. The file itself is then automatically named `filename_0.jpg` instead of `filename.jpg`, but the filename variable of the ImageField I'm accessing stays `filename.jpg`.

This of course leads to the old image being displayed. It seems the filename variable does not do what I expected, what would be the correct way to access the Imagecache generated files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Contemplate module is not recommended since it puts PHP code into the database which is generally considered a security vulnerability and non-performant.

You want to use [theme('imagecache', ...)](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--imagecache--imagecache.module/function/theme_imagecache/6) instead, which will return the HTML img tag with the proper path.